# Running External Tools from IntelliJ not finding Python libraries

Tags: intellij-idea, makefile, pyqt, pyqt4, pycharm

I've setup a few **External Tools** in IntelliJ (PyCharm) to run **pyuic4** and **pyrcc4** which are command line utilities used with PyQt to compile QRC resource files and Qt Designer .ui files into Python .py source files.

I've also created a Makefile to run the above tools in one go. When I run either from the terminal, everything works 100%.

I'm finding issues when trying to run these from within IntelliJ, its complaining that it can't find the module named PyQt4, here's the output:

```
/usr/bin/make all
/usr/local/bin/pyuic4 resources/ui/mainwindow.ui -o output/ui_mainwindow.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pyqt/4.9.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 31, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
make: *** [output/ui_mainwindow.py] Error 1

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I'm assuming this is to do because the External Tools aren't using the same environment variables as when run from the terminal?

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to rectify this in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135688/104891) for the instructions how to make GUI apps environment the same as in Terminal.

Another option is to start PyCharm from the Terminal so that it inherits the environment:

```
open -a /Applications/PyCharm.app/
```

Comment: This works, I've fiddled with some of the examples from the link, but I can't seem to get them working 100%. Thanks for the answer!